# Create .desktop launcher to start a terminal with a python virtual environment enable

Tags: gnome, launcher, gnome-terminal, source

Despite the similar questions/answers I can find on this forum and on others, I am not able to create a desktop launcher that start a terminal with a python environment activated.

To activate the environment in an open terminal, the command is `source /pyvenv/mne/bin/activate`.

My best guess, not working, is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Terminal-MNE
Exec=gnome-terminal --window -e "bash -c 'source /pyvenv/mne/bin/activate'"
Icon=org.gnome.Terminal
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application
```

Any better idea?

Comment: If the downvote could be accompanied by an explanation, I would gladly improve the question if it means a solution to the issue I haven't been able to solve in hours.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think it's a bad solution. If you always want to run something for the interactive shell, this is how you do it https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129144

Comment: Editing the `.bashrc` is not a solution in my case. Most of the time, I do want the default shell, but I would also like to create a shortcut to a shell with this environment activated. The reason is that most of my users don't know about 'source' and editing bashrc or bash profile, thus a shortcut to enable this shell with this env would be useful.

Comment: In that case I think your proposal is good, but you should probably have clarified the use case more in the question. I was wondering why you didn't just activate it universally or just run the command when you need it. By if you're a system admin and want to handle this for non-technical users a secondary desktop entry for "terminal with pyenv" makes sense.

I upvoted the question. It's not a bad question. People here can be way too harsh.

Comment: @Albin Thank you, agree I should have clarified the use case. Despite the month old, I still haven't figured out how to get it working, although it fell to the bottom of my priority list :/